# How to fix this regex in order to catch specific characters of a string?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I have a `very_largeString` that contains a list of words and and some `id`, i would like to extract  all the words and it's `id` that have `NC` and `AQ` that **morphologically ocurre consecutevely** and print the rest of the `id`. For example:

```
very_largeString= ''' Hola hola I 1
compis compis NCMS000 0.500006
! ! Fat 1

esta este DD0FS0 0.986779
y y CC 0.999962
es ser VSIP3S0 1
que que CS 0.437483
es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
sencilla sencillo AQ0FS0 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
utilizar utilizar VMN0000 1
, , Fc 1
que que CS 0.437483
si si CS 0.99954
nos nos PP1CP000 0.935743
ponen poner VMIP3P0 1
facilidad facilidad NCFS000 1
con con SPS00 1
las el DA0FP0 0.970954
tareas tarea NCFP000 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
casa casa NCFS000 0.979058
pues pues CS 0.998047
mejor mejor AQ0CS0 0.873665
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
mejor mejor AQ0CS0 0.873665
, , Fc 1
pero pero CC 0.999764
tan tan RG 1
antigua antiguo AQ0FS0 0.953488
que que CS 0.437483
según según SPS00 0.995943
mi mi DP1CSS 0.999101
madre madre NCFS000 1
era ser VSII1S0 0.491262
de de SPS00 0.999984
carga carga NCFS000 0.952569
superior superior AQ0CS0 0.992424
'''
```

this will be the desired output, since they have at the begining of the `id` the `NC` and `AQ` characters:

```
[('carga', 'NCFS000', 'superior', 'AQ0CS0'), ('carga', 'NCFS000', 'frontal', 'AQ0CS0')]
```

How can i fix my regex in order to extract all the words that have as id **`AQ`** and **`NC`**?. This is what i all ready tried:

```
regex_ = re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s\w+\s(NCFS000)\s[0-9.]+\n^(\w+)\s\w+\s(AQ0CS0)', very_largeString, re.M)

print regex_
```

The output is just the word and it´s associated `id` for example:

```
 [('word','id'),('word','id')]
```

Comment: Well your desired output would not match the actual output, I am guessing you didn't list the other combinations of your output?

Comment: I just want to focus on all the words that have NC and AQ as an id  and occur one after the other (i.e. no spaces, no other words and ids)

Answer (score 1):

```
from pprint import pprint
import re
result = re.findall(r'''
    (?mx)              # Muti-line, verbose
    ^                  # Align to beginning of a line
    (\S+)\s+           # Grab first word
    \S+\s+             # Don't care about 2nd word
    (NC\S+)\s+         # 3rd word must have NC
    \S+\n              # End of first line
    ^                  # Next line is identical in form
    (\S+)\s+           # to the first line
    \S+\s+       
    (AQ\S+)\s+         # except 3rd word must have AQ
    \S+\n
''', very_largeString)
pprint (result)
```

Comment: This is the output: `[('carga', 'NCFS000', 'superior', 'AQ0CS0'),
 ('punto', 'NCMS000', 'medio', 'AQ0MS0'),
 ('color', 'NCMS000', 'blanco', 'AQ0MS0'),
 ('carga', 'NCFS000', 'frontal', 'AQ0CS0'),
 ('ruido', 'NCMS000', 'jeje', 'NCMS000')]` the problem with this is the last parethesis `('ruido', 'NCMS000', 'jeje', 'NCMS000')` i can't return the same id (i.e.`NCMS000,NCMS000`) i can only return `NC` and `AQ`.

Comment: And did you apply the obvious fix? See the recent edit of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you´re trying to do some NLP (Natural Language Processing), and you want to extract from some Spanish corpus the pairs composed by a `noun` and a `qualifier`. There are already tools for such tasks.

I recomend you to take a look at [Python Natural Language Tool Kit](http://www.nltk.org/) (NLTK).

Also I have to say is not a common task perform these operations on a corpus instead on completely natural text.  I think you should explain your intensions, perhaps the solution you're trying to achive is not the best solution for your actual problem.

Help us to help you.